# Find $ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{a}^{b} \frac{\sin (nx)}{x} dx$

Tags: real-analysis

> For $0 < a < b$,  find
>   $$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{a}^{b} \frac{\sin (nx)}{x} dx.$$

My attempt :
$$\int_{a}^{b} \frac{\sin (nx)}{x} dx= \sin x\int_{a}^{b}\frac{1}{x}dx -\int_{a}^{b}\cos x\cdot \log x dx $$
after that I'm not  able  to proceed  further.

Pliz  help me. Any hints/solution?

Thanks

Comment: Where did the $n$ go to?

Comment: By Lebesgue-Riemann Lemma, the limit is $0$

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown $\infty$

Comment: Hint: the integral is $\int_{na}^{nb}\frac{\sin x\,dx}{x}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\int_a^b\frac{\sin nx}x\,dx=\left[-\frac{\cos nx}{nx}\right]_a^b-
\int_a^b\frac{\cos nx}{nx^2}\,dx
=\frac{\cos na}{na}-\frac{\cos nb}{nb}-\frac1n\int_a^b\frac{\cos nx}{x^2}\,dx.$$
There are some very convenient denominators here!

Comment: Second equation is wrong. Should be $\frac{\cos(na)}{na}-\frac{\cos(nb)}{nb}$. Good answer. +1

Answer (score 3):

Hint. We assume that $0<a<b$. By letting $t=nx$, we have that
$$\int_{a}^{b} \frac{\sin (nx)}{x} dx=\int_{na}^{nb} \frac{\sin (t)}{t} dt
=\int_{0}^{nb} \frac{\sin (t)}{t} dt-\int_{0}^{na} \frac{\sin (t)}{t} dt.$$
Now note that the integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (t)}{t} dt$ is convergent (see for example [$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx $ converges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2085462/int-0-infty-frac-sin-xxdx-converges)?).